# View of the Shu"t Min HaShamayim

Tags: posek-psak-decisor-ruling, rishonim, heaven

The [Shu"t Min Hashamayim](https://www.sefaria.org/Shut_min_haShamayim.1?lang=bi) was written by a Rishon who would receive answers in dreams from Heaven. Is there a difference in Torah views regarding how to weigh the halachic perspective of such a work? (i.e. The Chida (Yosef Ometz 82) seems to favor the sefer at times, but do others agree/disagree/neutral leaning)

Comment: Very related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14912/13438

Answer (score 2):

Rav Reuven Margaliot presents a survey of sources from Chazal through Acharonim in the introduction of his critical edition of Shu"t Min HaShamayim, in which he makes a very strong argument that dreams play a pivotal role in deciding Halacha, peshat in a Pasuk, and more.

Rav Ovadia has a few Teshvuot (Yabia Omer vol. 1 Orach Chaim 40-42, vol. 5 Orach Chaim Siman 43, vol. 9 Orach Chaim Siman 103:5; Yechaveh Daat 1:68) where he argues with the Chida and rereads some of the aforementioned sources in disfavor of asking Halachic questions Min HaShamayim. In fact, according to the Rambam, asking questions min hashamayim might be tantamount to Navi HaSheker! (middle of Yabia Omer 1:OC:40)

Comment: "In fact, according to the Rambam, asking questions min hashamayim might be tantamount to Navi HaSheker! (middle of Yabia Omer 1:OC:40)" @MDjava you really should bring the actual text on this from Rav Yosef in addition to your citation. It would be a surprise that he would be making the statement that argues Sh"ut Min HaShamayim is considered to be equated with the din of a Navi Sheker even according to Rambam.

Comment: Yabia Omer is not Me'ever LaYam or Bashamayim that you should have to cross the sea to get itכִּֽי־קָר֥וֹב אֵלֶ֛יךָ הַדָּבָ֖ר מְאֹ֑ד בְּפִ֥יךָ וּבִֽלְבָבְךָ֖ לַעֲשֹׂתֽוֹ׃. The sefer is readily available in many Batei Midrashot around the world.

Comment: It isn’t about my access to my set of Yabia Omer. It’s about improving your answer. You are making a very big statement of your understanding of Rav Yosef’s response with only a page citation. For him to be stating that as he understood Rambam the Shu’t Min HaShamayim (something quoted by many poskim as authoritative) to be compared to a false prophet is out of character with Rav Yosef, in general. Not impossible, but unusual. It deserves more than a simple page citation.