# To say Kaddish if known the person has gone to Gan Eden

Tags: halacha, mourning-aveilus, kaddish, gan-eden

This story https://www.theyeshivaworld.com/news/headlines-breaking-stories/1819358/tzaddik-of-bnei-brak-appears-in-dream-to-fellow-kovno-ghetto-survivor-im-already-in-gan-eden.html

Got me thinking if it’s known that the person has gone to Gan Eden does those who say Kaddish need to continue saying it?

Comment: Kaddish is about the grieving and bereavement period for those who are left behind, accepting Hashem's kingship. Why would a personal loss be affected by the dream? The dead person is still missed.

Comment: @rosends, not exactly. We say Kaddish for a year because that it the time that a wicked person is in gehenom for, but we cut that down to eleven months to not say that the deceased was wicked. Why Kaddish? As you said.

Comment: "*if it's known*"?  How can anyone know that about anyone for certain?

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost we do  not rely on dreams since many times they are nonsensical. In fact ,the Noda B'Yehuda writes in Yoreh Deah Tinyana siman 30 he notes that dreams are not reliable and writes " where do we ever see halacha learned from a dream!?!?".further in the teshuva he writes " to bring a proof from a dream is nonsense and nothing at all".

Besides for the reason above one of the  reason why the kaadish was instituted for a mourner was to show that the family accepts the loss of their family member by sanctifying HaShems name in a public forum,and show that they still believe in G-d.

Comment: Both this linked question and the answers are in conflict with your assumption concerning dreams. https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14912/7303

Comment: Mine or the Noda BYehuda?

Comment: In that teshuvos the NB himself says this regarding Rishonim,so ur question is on the NB,and I am well aware of Shu"t Min Hashmayim (I in fact own one) ,that's why I gave another possible reason

Comment: As I’m looking over this response about the kashrut of this particular fish, the NB doesn’t seem to know what to make of dreams (particularly after looking at the notes). It sounds more like he is saying that the way the questioner was applying that specific reference was inappropriate, not that the NB was making a blanket statement that dreams are never used in deciding halacha.

Comment: You are entitled to your opinion, but I think you are reading the teshuva incorrectly just like you believe I am reading incorrectly

Answer (score 1):

Given that we say kaddish on the yahrtzeit even though the neshama is assumed to be in Gan Eden, we should say kaddish for the first 11 months in any case. We would be saying kaddish so that the neshama should have an aliyah no matter how small any aveiros might be or even if the neshama immediately is placed at an initial level in Gan Eden. I am assuming that this is a parent that you are saying kaddish for as anyone else would not require you to say kaddish at all.

Comment: Siblings, wife, Husband, I think for 30 days. This question is purely theoretical.

Comment: @DanielRoss I was assuming that it involved the year. However, my point was that even within Gan Eden there are levels and we want to help the neshama move up.

Answer (score 0):

The source for saying Kaddish for the deceased is from [Kalla Rabbasi 2:9](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Tractate_Kallah_Rabbati.2?lang=bi) (as mentioned by the Darchei Moshe Y.D. 376:8):

> ט ברייתא קטנים מקבלים פני שכינה שנאמר זרע יעבדנו יסופר לה׳ לדור: [גמ׳] איבעיא להו מכפרין עון אבות או לא, ת״ש דר׳ עקיבא נפק לההוא אתרא אשכחיה לההוא גברא דהוי דרי טונא אכתפיה ולא הוה מצי לסגויי ביה והוה צוח ומתאנח, א״ל מאי עבידתיך א״ל לא שבקנא איסורא דלא עבידנא בההיא עלמא ועכשיו איכא נטורין עילוון ולא שבקין לי דאינוח א״ל רבי עקיבא שבקת ברא א״ל בחייך לא תשלין דדחילנא ממלאכי דמחו לי בפולסי דנורא ואמרין לי אמאי לא תיתי בפריע א״ל אימא ליה דקא ניחותך, א״ל שבקית אתתא מעברתא אזל ר׳ עקיבא עאל לההיא מדינתא, אמר להו בריה דפלוני היכא (ליה) אמרו ליה יעקר זכרו דההוא שחיק עצמות א״ל אמאי אמרו ליה ההוא לסטים אכל אינשי ומצער בריתא ולא עוד אלא שבא על נערה המאורסה ביום הכפורים. אזל לביתיה אשכח אתתיה מעוברתא נטרה עד דילדה , אזל מהליה לכי גדל אוקמי׳ בבי כנישתא לברוכי בקהלא לימים אזל ר׳ עקיבא לההוא אתרא איתחזי ליה א״ל תנוח דעתך שהנחת את דעתי:

To summarize, Rebbi Akiva saw a dead man suffering from his punishment, and he wanted to save the dead man from his suffering. To do that he found the dead man's son, and had him say berachos for the congregation. Rebbi Akiva later found that the dead man was settled.

The Beis Yosef brings a similar story from the Zohar where the son says Kaddish or the Haftarah.

According to this the whole purpose of saying Kaddish is to bring the deceased to Gan Eden, and if one were to know that he is already there , then there would be no point.